# How to show that $k < m_1+2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Let 
>   $$m_1 < m_2 < \dots <m_{k − 1} < m_k$$
>   be distinct positive integers such that their reciprocals are in arithmetic progression.
>
> 1. Show that $k < m_1+2$.
> 2. Give an example of such a sequence of length $k$ for any positive
>      integer $k$.

My approach : $$\frac{1}{m_k}=\frac{1}{m_1}+(k-1)d \\
\frac{m_1-m_k}{m_1m_kd}=k-1$$
So $d$ must be a fraction.  Am I going right?

Comment: Please check if the edited statement is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards the first part see [Integer reciprocals in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278979/integer-reciprocals-in-arithmetic-progression) .

For the second part, given a positive integer $k$, you may try the integer sequence
$$\frac{k!}{k}<\frac{k!}{k-1}<\dots<\frac{k!}{3}<\frac{k!}{2}<k!$$
then the difference between the reciprocals of two consecutive terms is $1/k!$.